# Instantiating Blobs in dartlang

Tags: dart, dart-html

I've been struggling to instantiate Blobs in dartlang as of late, but i worked out how to do it in version 8640

For those interested (I couldn't find an example anywhere on the net) 
I did this:

```dart
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(); 
req.open("GET", "http://...", true); 
req.responseType="blob"; 
req.overrideMimeType("image/png"); 
req.on.load.add( (event) { 
  if(req.readyState==4) { 
   Blob blob = req.response; // note NOT req.responseBlob 
    fileReader.on.load.add( (evt) { 
      document.query('#myimage').src=evt.target.result; 
    }); 
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
  } 
}); 
req.send();
```

I hope this helps somebody :)

Comment: Nice example. Dart Editor flags the line: `document.query('#myimage').src= evt.target.result;` with a "result is not a member of EventTarget" warning; we can remove this (if we are a little obsessive) by replacing the line with: `document.query('#myimage').src= (evt.target as FileReader).result;`

Comment: ...or simply `document.query('#myimage').src = fileReader.result;` since it is already named...

Answer (score 3):

If anyone landed here trying to figure out how to call the `Blob` constructor like I did, you actually need to feed it a list of lists (i.e. a `List<List<int>>`).

So, if you have a list of integers:

```
var binary = [1, 2, 3];
```

You pass it to the `Blob` constructor thusly:

```
var blorp = new Blob([binary]);
```

Calling `var blorp = new Blob(binary);` will result in a confusing message, claiming that the constructor wants a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

From the answer embedded in the question above:

```dart
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(); 
req.open("GET", "http://...", true); 
req.responseType="blob"; 
req.overrideMimeType("image/png"); 
req.on.load.add( (event) { 
  if(req.readyState==4) { 
   Blob blob = req.response; // note NOT req.responseBlob 
    fileReader.on.load.add( (evt) { 
      document.query('#myimage').src=evt.target.result; 
    }); 
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
  } 
}); 
req.send();
```